# ¿Por qué decimos "se me acerca/parece" o "se le acerca/parece", pero no "*te le acerco" o "*me le acercas"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, pronombres

Esta pregunta me surgió leyendo [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32251/) en la que se cita este fragmento del apartado 16.14i de la [*Nueva gramática de la lengua española*](https://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica):

> No se duplican necesariamente los complementos indirectos tónicos que expresan dirección (§35.4j), por lo que se asimilan en cierta medida a los complementos de régimen. Los verbos que los seleccionan alternan las formas tónicas del complemento indirecto pronominal, sin duplicación obligatoria (*Se acercó a mí*, [...]) con las variantes átonas (*Se me acercó*, [...]). [...] Como se ha señalado, entienden algunos autores que las primeras variantes pueden interpretarse como complementos de régimen [...].

Yo creo que lo que se explica aquí no tiene que ver únicamente con expresar dirección porque el verbo "parecerse" tiene exactamente el mismo comportamiento: "se parece a él/ella" (sin duplicación pronominal obligatoria) / "se le parece".

No sé si estos "a mí" y "a él/ella" se deben considerar complementos indirectos o  complementos de régimen (como se menciona en el texto citado), pero, en cualquier caso, tienen un comportamiento peculiar porque podemos hacer estas sustituciones

> - Se acerca / se parece a mí --> se me acerca / parece
> - Se acerca / se parece a ti --> se te acerca / parece
> - Se acerca / se parece a él/ella --> se le acerca / parece
> - Se acerca / se parece a nosotros --> se nos acerca / parece
> - Se acerca / se parece a vosotros --> se os acerca / parece
> - Se acerca / se parece a ellos/ellas --> se les acerca / parece
> - Me acerco / parezco a ti --> te me acerco / parezco
> - Te acercas / pareces a mí --> te me acercas / pareces
> - [...]

pero no estas otras

> - Me acercas a él/ella --> *me le acercas
> - Me acercaste a él/ella --> *me le acercaste
> - Te acerco a él/ella --> *te le acerco
> - Te acerqué a él/ella     --> *te le acerqué
> - Me acerca a él/ella --> *me le acerca
> - Me acercó a él/ella --> *me le acercó
> - Te acerca a él/ella --> *te le acerca
> - Te acercó a él/ella --> *te le acercó
> - ¿Hay más? ¿Hay también construcciones de este tipo que son imposibles con "parecerse"?

Cuando había empezado a redactar la pregunta pensaba que también había combinaciones de pronombres imposibles con "parecerse": pensándolo mejor, quizás no, pero no estoy del todo segura.

¿Sabríais explicarme por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 1):

#### Respuesta corta

La regla parece ser que en los verbos **ditransitivos** (no pronomimales) donde el complemento **directo** es de primera o segunda persona, el complemento **indirecto** no se puede sustituir por un pronombre átono.

#### Explicación

El fenómeno que observas no se debe al uso de complementos indirectos sin duplicación pronominal obligatoria (con verbos como *acercar(se), parecerse* y otros muchos), sino al uso de verbos **ditransitivos** donde tanto el complemento directo como el indirecto son personas. Por ejemplo, la siguiente sustitución no es posible:

- Te venderá a un traficante de esclavos -> <s>Te le venderá</s>.

En el 16.11d y 16.11e de la [Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española (NGLE)](https://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica) se trata este tema, aunque solo en el caso de que ninguno de los dos complementos sean de tercera persona. En el 16.11d, se pone el ejemplo

> Te me devolvieron

que, teóricamente, podría tener cualquiera de las dos siguientes interpretaciones:

- Te devolvieron a mí
- Me devolvieron a ti

El 16.11d de la NGLE indica que la interpretación correcta es "Te devolvieron a mí", por lo que la frase "Me devolvieron a ti" **no admite** sustitución del complemento indirecto por un pronombre. Sin embargo, se indica que *te me devolvieron* es una construcción antigua, y el 16.11f dice que

> suelen resultar forzadas las oraciones en las que se combinan dos pronombres átonos cuando ninguno de ellos aparece en tercera persona. Se admiten por tanto oraciones como *Nos los recomendaron* [...], pero el español de hoy rechaza otras como [...] *Te me entregó* [...]

Entiendo que esta regla solo afecta a los verbos ditransitivos pero no a los pronominales: "te me entregó" no es correcto pero "no te me acerques" sí lo es.

En cuanto a los verbos ditransitivos donde el complemento directo y el indirecto son personas y alguno de ellos es de tercera persona, no he encontrado ninguna regla en la NGLE. Pero parece ser que, en verbos no pronominales, **no se puede sustituir un complemento indirecto de tercera persona si el complemento directo es de primera o segunda persona**. Es decir, se puede sustituir

- Lo acercas a mí -> Me lo acercas

pero no

- Me acercas a él -> <s>Me le acercas</s>

Se me ocurren dos razones para esto:

- Estamos acostumbrados a que el pronombre de complemento indirecto aparezca antes que el de complemento directo. Esta regla tiene menor precedencia que la regla "segunda>primera>tercera" persona (ver NGLE, 16.11a), por lo que la regla "indirecto>directo" se debe violar en casos como "<s>me le acercas</s>". Esto nos suena extraño, y por tanto no lo hacemos.
- En regiones con leísmo, construcciones como "<s>me le acercas</s>" son ambiguas: una persona leísta diría "me le acercas" en ambos casos: "lo acercas a mí" y "me acercas a él". Esta razón no tiene mucho peso, dado que construcciones como "te le acercas" ("te acercas a él", reflexivo) y "te lo acercas" ("lo acercas a ti", ditransitivo) son válidas, y también serían ambiguas para un leísta.

El verbo *parecer(se)* no puede ser ditransitivo, por lo que con este verbo todas las sustituciones deberían ser posibles.

Comment: @Charo sí, porque esos son usos **reflexivos** del verbo *acercarse*. Por eso hago la distinción entre reflexivo y ditransitivo.

Comment: Vale: el argumento es que hay que distinguir entre "acercarse" verbo pronominal (para mí reflexivos son "lavarse", "peinarse", etc.) y "acercar" verbo ditransitivo (no pronominal). Y lo mismo pasaría, por ejemplo, con "presentarse" pronominal que se comporta de manera diferente que "presentar" ditransitivo.

Comment: @Charo exactamente.

Comment: He tardado en tener tiempo de leer tu respuesta con detenimiento: me parece una buena respuesta, aunque quizás no definitiva.

Comment: Lo curioso es que, a mí, "te me acerca" no me suena mal.

Comment: @Charo "te me acerca" es como "te me devolvieron" : podría ser "te acerca a mí" o "me acerca a ti", según la NGLE es "te acerca a mí", y la NGLE dice que "el español actual lo rechaza", aunque a mí también me suena bien... Pero he preferido en mi respuesta hacer caso a la RAE en los casos en los que la RAE dice algo.

Comment: He encontrado este [libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=Uy4n9MzmDJQC&pg=PA599&lpg=PA599&dq=%22me+le+acercas%22&source=bl&ots=r8_wTwjgsg&sig=ACfU3U2wxpGrlig8FQzEYTAWjr0sG-HssA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHuqWGjtbnAhUMyIUKHWMsDtcQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22me%20le%20acercas%22&f=false) que habla de este fenómeno.

Comment: Pero, si he entendido bien los argumentos que dan, vienen a decir que en 1976 se intentó explicar mediante una restricción, aunque esta explicación no es del todo satisfactoria porque hay construcciones como "te me presentaron" que violan esa restricción, pero son aceptadas por algunos hablentes (y rechazadas por otros).