# Los objectos en el modismo "caérsele la baba"

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos

El modismo español "caérsele la baba" significa gustar mucho.
Uno de los ejemplos es "A su madre se le cae la baba con su bebé de seis meses."
No entiendo a qué tipos de objecto "se" y "le" pertenecen en este modismo.

Comment: Does this question and answer help https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32243/redundant-indirect-object-pronoun-is-le-redundant-in-pregunt%c3%a9mosle-al-est%c3%bapi

Answer (score 1):

"le" es el objeto indirecto que pertenece "a ella" en este caso, y "se" es el reflexivo. Van unidos despues de un infinitivo pero se separan si se posicionan antes de un verbo conjugado: "se le cae" vs. "caersele."

Answer (score 1):

- [*Caerse*](https://dle.rae.es/caer) es un verbo pronominal (reflexivo) en este modismo

  > 1. intr. Dicho de un cuerpo: Moverse de arriba abajo por la acción de su propio peso. U. t. c. prnl.

  Es decir, "se" se refiere al sujeto, *la baba*.
- *le* es un [*dativo simpatético* o *dativo posesivo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26172/24236): se refiere a *su madre*, e indica que "la baba" es de ella.