# Redundancia en el complemento directo

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-directos, complemento-directo

Un conocido está estudiando español y no he sido capaz de encontrar una respuesta más o menos buena a esto.

Pongamos un par de ejemplos:

> - El pan **lo** compré ayer
> - Ayer compré el pan

> - Todo eso **lo** recuerdo
> - Recuerdo todo eso

¿Por qué es necesario escribir "**lo**" en el primer caso de cada ejemplo?

Comment: Excepto en el caso de énfasis o contraste (*aquello no sé, pero *este* compraré*), cuando el complemento directo o indirecto va antepuesto el verbo, es obligatorio la reduplicación.  Es imposible decir por qué es regla a parte de por qué sí (o por que así quieren hablar los hispanohablantes), pero imagino que se debe en parte a un deseo para evitar que se le considere el sujeto.  En el caso de énfasis/contraste, se supone que el contexto lo hace perclaro.

Comment: La duplicación mediante el pronombre es debida a que en la primera versión de cada frase hay una dislocación a la izquierda del objeto directo: puedes encontrar una explicación en la parte final de [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32957/). Es un fenómeno que se da también en otras lenguas románicas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El fenómeno que está en juego aquí se llama *dislocación a la izquierda* y no es exclusivo del español: se da también en otras lenguas románicas. Podemos encontrar una explicación y algunos ejemplos en la [*Enciclopedia de lingüística hispánica*](https://books.google.es/books?id=GkF-CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA574).

Una *dislocación a la izquierda* consiste en un sintagma nominal que actúa como complemento del verbo que se sitúa al principio de una frase. Cuando se trata de un objeto directo, como en la primera versión de cada una de las frases de la pregunta, o de un objeto indirecto, como norma general este complemento se debe repetir en la oración en forma de un pronombre clítico. Esta es la razón por la cual en la primera versión de cada frase de la pregunta aparece el pronombre "lo".

Otro ejemplo parecido, proveniente del libro citado, sería

> Ese libro ya lo he leído

en el cual se disloca a la izquierda (es decir, se coloca al principio de la frase) el objeto directo "ese libro": puedes ver cómo el objeto directo aparece de nuevo en la oración bajo la forma del pronombre "lo".

Un par de ejemplos más de dislocación a la izquierda de complementos directos sacados del mismo libro, en los que se puede observar la duplicación mediante el pronombre "la":

> - La conferencia plenaria, la dará la doctora Pujol.
> - A la doctora Pujol aún no la hemos visto.

También podemos dislocar a la izquierda un objeto indirecto, fenómeno que requiere asimismo de la duplicación mediante un pronombre clítico, como en este ejemplo:

> A Juan le dieron un premio.

Las dislocaciones a la izquierda de objetos directos e indirectos requieren la duplicación del objeto en la frase a través de un pronombre clítico. Hay una excepción a esta regla, explicada en el libro que hemos citado: cuando el objeto dislocado es un sintagma nominal indefinido no se produce necesariamente duplicación del objeto mediante un clítico debido a que en español no existen clíticos indefinidos. Es lo que se puede observar en este ejemplo:

> Carpetas rojas, yo no he visto.

En el capítulo titulado "Estructura de la información" del libro anteriormente citado se puede encontrar información muy detallada sobre las razones que dan lugar a este fenómeno, pero, resumidamente,  podemos decir que en castellano (como también en otras lenguas románicas) tendemos a transmitir la información de manera que las novedades aparezcan después de las cosas conocidas. Por este motivo, frecuentemente sentimos la necesidad de alterar el orden sujeto-verbo-complementos en la frase (es esencialmente el que corresponde a la segunda versión de las oraciones de la pregunta), que es el que percibimos como neutro, sobre todo en la conversación oral. Las dislocaciones a la izquierda son uno de los recursos que nos proporciona la lengua para conseguirlo.

Poniendo algún ejemplo de la misma fuente, en una conversación entre dos personas, la frase

> La doctora Pujol dará una conferencia

tiene un orden de palabras y se pronunciaría con una entonación neutros. Pero si están hablando de la conferencia plenaria y la novedad que quiere transmitir una de ellas a la otra es quién dará esa conferencia, la oración que diría sería la siguiente

> La conferencia plenaria, la dará la doctora Pujol

en la cual podemos observar el fenómeno de la dislocación a la izquierda del objeto directo, que es un referente previamente conocido por los dos interlocutores.

Comment: A veces pienso que nuestro idioma está roto :) Gran explicación!

Comment: @dimasdmm: ¿En qué sentido "está roto"?

Comment: @Charo, en el caso del de Sintagma Nominal indefinido se podría decir, y creo que correctamente, "carpetas rojas, yo no las he visto", refiriéndome a todas las carpetas, es decir que según mi conocimiento no existen las "carpetas rojas", incluso en el habla podría expresar dubitativamente "carpetas rojas", cambia **carpetas rojas** por **marcianos** y lo verás...

Comment: Mmmm... Creo que tienes razón, @AndrésChandía. El ejemplo y la explicación los he sacado de las páginas 577-578 del libro citado, pero tu frase me suena bien. En todo caso, he modificado ligeramente mi respuesta. De todas formas, lo que ocurre en castellano es que no existe el clítico "en" o "ne" que tienen otras lenguas románicas, que es el que "debería" ponerse en este tipo de construcciones: de alguna manera se sustituye ese clítico por nada.