# Omission of complements: cases where this is not allowed? (question about reddit Spanish wiki)

Tags: pronombres, sintaxis, objetos-indirectos

The reddit r/learnspanish wiki has a section called ["Omission of Complements."](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnspanish/wiki/index/faq/#wiki_.2022_omission_of_complements)

It discusses differences in meaning or emphasis between pairs of sentences like the following:

- Me castigaron. / Me castigaron a mí.
- Le dieron el premio. / A ella le dieron el premio.

I asked someone **when it is grammatically correct and meaning-preserving** to omit an indirect complement when a corresponding pronoun is present (like "me or "le" above). As I understand it, they told me the following:

1. The meaning will not be clear if you omit the indirect complement without the context to understand what the pronoun refers to (e.g. it would have to be clear that "Le" refers to "A ella").
2. Even if the corresponding pronoun is present and its meaning is clear, there are still cases where omitting the indirect complement is ungrammatical. These cases do not follow a small number of easily explained general rules.

If that is correct, can you **give me some examples of #2**, where the following are all true?

- We have a grammatically correct sentence including an indirect complement and a corresponding pronoun.
- From the context, we know what the pronoun refers to, even if we omit the indirect complement.
- If we omit the indirect complement, the sentence becomes ungrammatical or changes its meaning.

Maybe I am not thinking about this in the best way. My quick google searches did not find very much discussion about the omission of complements, and a native speaker told me that it's better to think about it the other way (ask "when must the complement be present?") rather than "when can the complement be omitted?"). Nevertheless, *if* I understood #2 correctly, there must be cases where I **need** to spell out the indirect complement.

Comment: Why don't you wait to find concrete examples instead of making us work for you by trying to follow your logic. It takes a lot of brain power to sit at a computer and come up with a bunch of examples that match your criteria exactly.

Comment: We have [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32243/24236) about the opposite case: when can't the pronoun be omitted. I cannot come up with any examples of your #2, where the pronoun is there but the named complement can't be omitted. I could not find any sources either but I would be surprised if such cases exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existen casos en los que necesite "deletrear" el complemento indirecto.

- We have a grammatically correct sentence including an indirect complement and a corresponding pronoun. ¡**Tírale**! (Tú)

From the context, we know what the pronoun refers to, even if we omit the indirect complement.  **¡Tira!**

Contexto: "Nosotros estamos parados en una señal de stop". Y decimos, !**Tira**!

> Context: "We are standing at a stop sign".  And we say, !**Tira**!

If we omit the indirect complement, the sentence becomes ungrammatical or changes its meaning.

¡ **Tírale**! / ¡**Tira**!

No, no siempre se convierte en agramatical. Aunque a veces pueden existir casos complicados en los que no aparece o no se recuerda el contexto y la oración puede volverse confusa.

> No, it doesn't always become ungrammatical. Although sometimes there
> can be complicated cases in which the context does not appear or is
> not remembered and the sentence can become confusing.

**Tírale Contexto**

- **¡Tírale!** = No viene ningún otro coche, **tú** puedes **tirar** (llevar) **el coche** más allá de la señal de "stop" e irnos. (tú tira del coche o lleva el coche).

---

A pesar de que existen numerosas frases de este tipo, sin embargo la cuestión no siempre explica, cuando se duda de un sujeto explícito, en contextos específicos.

Para percatarse de los aspectos que envuelve todos los anexos del "**Complemento Indirecto**", lo que necesita es partir de las dudas que se fijen en su mente tomando vocabulario especializado que le ayude a distinguir entre las diferencias existentes dentro del propio "Complemento Indirecto". Para ello es importante que conozca "La Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española" y de esta manera centrar mucho mejor el foco de atención en todas las referencias y léxico que hace mención al respecto del complemento indirecto.

La**NUEVA GRAMÁTICA DE LA LENGUA ESPAÑOLA. MANUAL** es de gran ayuda para profundizar en los distintos aspectos de interés, pues aparecen bajo epígrafes de forma determinada y clasificada, multitud de ejemplos de los que puede sacar derivar conclusiones o nuevas preguntas siguiendo los conceptos y terminología que plantea la "Nueva Gramática"

[image]

https://www.academia.edu/29461718/RAE_Manual_de_la_Nueva_Gram%C3%A1tica_de_la_Lengua_Espa%C3%B1ola

El **complemento indirecto a nivel más avanzado es complicado**, si aún esta interesado arriba le indico una referencia, en español, donde poder descargar la **NUEVA GRAMÁTICA DE LA LENGUA ESPAÑOLA. MANUAL.** y con paciencia podrá traducir, estudiar o indicarle a su profesor que le explique poco a poco cualquiera de los campos más complejos donde se inserten sus dudas;

**Repaso General en donde encontrará ejemplos que seguro le gustan.**

**El Complemento indirecto**

35.1 - El complemento indirecto. Sus clases.

35.2 - Constitución del complemento indirecto.

35.3 - Complementos indirectos seleccionados o argumentales.

35.4 - Complementos indirectos no seleccionados o no argumentales.

---

35.1.2 Clases de complementos indirectos

**La función de complemento indirecto es particularmente controvertida
porque no tiene encaje fácil en la distinción entre argumentos y adjuntos.**

Cabe decir, en efecto, que el pronombre dativo "**le**" que aparece en **Le di el regalo** representa uno de los tres argumentos del verbo dar.

No obstante, también son pronombres dativos en;

- No **me** lo enoje
- **Me** apagó la luz

Pronombres que no parecen ser argumentales.

Los complementos indirectos pueden dividirse en;

- seleccionados, argumentales o actanciales

y en

- no seleccionados, no argumentales o no actanciales

Se interpretan como complementos indirectos **argumentales** (los que designan al
destinatario de una acción) y también los llamados **experimentantes**, que se refieren al individuo que experimenta la noción que el verbo designa.

- *Me gustan las manzanas*

[image]

Por otra parte hay que saber que cuando el pronombre **le/les se emplea en las oraciones impersonales** que también contienen complementos directos de persona en masculino, no es dativo sino acusativo.

Así en esta frase "**le**" es complemento directo de "**querer**"

- "Si supiera cuánto se le quiere en el Perú".

Hay que tener en cuenta las construcciones formadas por algunos verbos pronominales de pensamiento y afección, tales como olvidar, antojar, ocurrir (en el sentido de venir algo a la mente) y que además del pronombre concordante con el sujeto, exigen otro en dativo.

De estas **construcciones doblemente pronominales** así formadas resultan **oraciones agramaticales** "*Se ocurrió una idea extravagante*", que requiere la presencia del dativo; "*Se (me, te, le, les...) ocurrió una idea extravagante*".

Los dativos que no desempeñan una función sintáctica ni se vinculan con ningún referente son muy frecuentes en México y Centroamérica.

*Leonor abrió la puerta y le dio gusto verme -Pásale por aquí- dijo.*

Estos dativos expresivos unidos a un imperativo o a una forma no verbal pueden dar lugar a  a expresiones interjectivas.

- Pues para luego es tarde.
- Éntrele - ándale (Imperativo)
- Acarreábamos baldes de agua o volvíamos a examinar los cuartos del fondo **híjole**

35.3.2 Dentro de los **indirectos seleccionados o argumentales** se encuentran los de término, origen y ubicación que se suelen alternar con complementos de régimen en los pares;

- Se acercó a ella / Se le acerco (dirección, destino o término).
- Se apartó de ellos / Se les apartó (origen procedencia fuente).
- Eché la sal a la ensalada  / Le eché sal a la ensalada (ubicación).

[image]

35.4 Complementos indirectos no seleccionados o no argumentales

35.4.1a Dativo de interés y dativo simpatético

35.4.1b El Dativo simpatético o posesivo se interpreta como un complemento indirecto de posesión.

El español expresa a menudo el poseedor mediante pronombres átonos de dativo en concurrencia con frases nominales que expresan la cosa poseída y que se construyen con determinante, como en;

- *Se le hincharon los pie.*
- *Se te nubló la vista.*
- *Se le torció el tobillo*.

El dativo simpatético es compatible con otros contenidos. Así, el pronombre **me** en "**Me duelen los oídos**", designa la persona a la que pertenecen los oídos, pero también a quien experimenta el dolor.

Por último sobre los **dativos aspectuales**, pueden reinterpretarse como morfemas de persona de los verbos sobre los que inciden.

A favor de la asimilación parcial en grupos verbales en función de que la forma se esté o no presente;

- saber algo (conocerlo)
- saberse algo (haberlo memorizado) frecuentemente en el español europeo.
- creer algo (tenerlo por cierto)
- creerse algo (aceptarlo de buena fe.
- llevar la palta (transportarla)
- llevarse la plata (salir o escaparse con ella, robarla).
- saltar una barrera (salvarla)
- saltarse una barrera (omitirla, no atenderla).
- encontrar a alguien (hallarlo)
- encontrarse a alguien (tropezárselo, dar con él sin buscarlo)
- esperar algo (tener esperanza en ello)
- esperarse algo (temer que vaya a a suceder)